# Unable to save the Background color on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, bundle, android-radiobutton

I am new to android application development, I am learning it by practicing few example and as well trying to implement my own ideas based on those examples...as a part of that i am trying to save the background color of the screen using Bundles and sharedpreferences.

This code is saving the color only once, but when i rotate the screen again application is getting crashed

```
package com.radiobuttonproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  OnCheckedChangeListener,
    OnClickListener {


// Initialisation area ....
RadioGroup myRadiogroup;
Button Apply;
TextView message;
RelativeLayout BackGround;
int CheckedId = 0;
SharedPreferences myPrefs;
Editor myEditor;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myRadiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);
    Apply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Apply);
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
    BackGround = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Background);

    Apply.setOnClickListener(this);
    // myRadiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


   // Tasks to be performed on click of the radiobutton 
    switch (checkedId) {

    case R.id.RadioButton1:
        BackGround.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        // Saving the color using the sharedpreferences....
        myPrefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        myEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        myEditor.putInt("CHECKEDBUTTON", R.id.RadioButton1);
        myEditor.commit();
        break;
    case R.id.RadioButton2:
        BackGround.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

         // Saving the color using the sharedpreferences....
        myPrefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        myEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        myEditor.putInt("CHECKEDBUTTON", R.id.RadioButton2);
        myEditor.commit();
        break;
    case R.id.RadioButton3:
        BackGround.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

         // Saving the color using the sharedpreferences....
        myPrefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        myEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        myEditor.putInt("CHECKEDBUTTON", R.id.RadioButton3);
        myEditor.commit();
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Setting the background color using the id from RadioButton
    CheckedId = myRadiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    onCheckedChanged(myRadiogroup, CheckedId);

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

     // Retrieving and Saving the color using the sharedpreferences and Bundle....
    CheckedId = myPrefs.getInt("CHECKEDBUTTON", 0);
    outState.putInt("CHECKEDBUTTON", CheckedId);

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    int getCheckedId = savedInstanceState.getInt("CHECKEDBUTTON");

     // Retrieving the color using the Bundle and setting it back to the background....
    switch (getCheckedId) {

    case R.id.RadioButton1:
        BackGround.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        break;
    case R.id.RadioButton2:
        BackGround.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        break;
    case R.id.RadioButton3:
        BackGround.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

    }
}

}
```

```js
02 - 22 21: 17: 35.468: I / Adreno - EGL(5727): < qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize: 410 > : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU()
02 - 22 21: 17: 35.468: I / Adreno - EGL(5727): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
02 - 22 21: 17: 35.468: I / Adreno - EGL(5727): Build Date: 03 / 07 / 14 Fri
02 - 22 21: 17: 35.468: I / Adreno - EGL(5727): Local Branch:
  02 - 22 21: 17: 35.468: I / Adreno - EGL(5727): Remote Branch: quic / LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
02 - 22 21: 17: 35.468: I / Adreno - EGL(5727): Local Patches: NONE
02 - 22 21: 17: 35.468: I / Adreno - EGL(5727): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 + NOTHING
02 - 22 21: 17: 35.540: D / OpenGLRenderer(5727): Enabling debug mode 0
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.755: D / AndroidRuntime(5727): Shutting down VM
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.755: W / dalvikvm(5727): threadid = 1: thread exiting with uncaught exception(group = 0x41667d40)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): Process: com.radiobuttonproject, PID: 5727
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): java.lang.NullPointerException
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at com.radiobuttonproject.MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MainActivity.java: 86)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java: 1161)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java: 1246)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 3779)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java: 139)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1216)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 136)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5086)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 515)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 785)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 601)
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: We need the stack trace from logcat. Please post it.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
02 - 22 21: 18: 14.831: E / AndroidRuntime(5727): at com.radiobuttonproject.MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MainActivity.java: 86)` what is line 86?  My guess it that `myPrefs` is null since I cannot see you initialise it anywhere except in the clickListener.

Comment: int SavedButton = myPrefs.getInt("CHECKEDBUTTON", 0);

Comment: Yep, `myPrefs` is null.

Answer (score 1):

You only initiate `myPrefs` when some of the RadioButtons is clicked. If you don't do that and rotate the app, you try to save the color to preferences that are not initialized and you get `NullPointerException`.